# Use sudo in service start CenstOS

Tags: linux, bash, service

when I tried this code in my service

```
start() {
    sudo -u userName "pwd" &>/home/log
}
```

I got this result in /home/log:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

and the service won't run, but when the server finishes starting up, the service will run when i call

service test start

Comment: What kind of service is it? How is the server program coded? In which programming language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A service is usually started as `root` from boot (or `/etc/init.d/`) scripts.

You could use the [`/bin/su` command](http://www.linfo.org/su.html) (as root) to change the user:

```
/bin/su -c "pwd; id" username
```

Read also about [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) programs and the [setuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) and [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html) syscalls. Take time to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to understand the relevant concepts.

Consider also having a `@reboot` entry for the user's [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).